# question on flex mxml reference

Tags: apache-flex

I declared a namespace at the top of my mxml file Radio.mxml;

```
xmlns:jour="components.journal.*"
```

I now have another mxml file Journal.mxml is under the components/journal folder,the Radio.mxml is at the root folder which contains the components folder.

Now I want to access the Journal.mxml in the Radio.mxml using the name space,how could I do that,I've tried

var a = new jour.Journal();

but it seems not right,could anyone help a little bit?Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xmlns:jour="components.journal.*"` only defines the namespace for you mxml components.  So you can do something like: `<jour:Journal id='my-journal' />`.

If you want use your `Journal` class inside of your actionscript, you'll need to import it seperately: `import components.journal.Journal` then use it like `var a = new Journal();`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're on the right track, but there is a slight disconnect.  You're mixing MXML and ActionScript syntax I think.

In ActionSCript you can do this:

```
import components.journal.Journal;
var a : Journal = new Journal();
```

In MXML, you would do something like this:

```
<TopLevelComponent xmlns:jour="components.journal.*">
  <jour:Journal />
</TopLevelComponent>
```

I do not believe that ActionScript can reference the namespace you define in MXML.

Comment: Thanks,I tried put the script in like this:

    <mx:Script><![CDATA[
       import components.journal.Journal;
  
      import mx.controls.Alert;
   
 internal function Handler():void {
   
 var a : Journal = new jour.Journal();}
]]></mx:Script>

It complains about "access of undefined property jour",could you help me on this please,thanks!

Comment: In the AS version I think you need to omit the "jour." portion after "new".

Comment: Right you are Wade; my typo.  Sorry about that!